# Create table entries in transparent tables?

Tags: abap

I have created one transparent table named `ZSID_TT`

I have also created data elements AND domains for each field.
saved and activated also.
But when I go to `Utilities --> TABLE CONTENTS --> there CREATE` entries has been disabled.

[image]

I am unable to enter data to this table.
And i am getting the following OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the response. I'll try to fix it soon.

Answer (score 5):

On the **Delivery and Maintenance** tab, set **Data Browser/Table View Maint.** to **Allowed**.

Comment: Then, please, mark the answer as the correct one to prevent others to try to fish points ;)